# Adjust size of MPMediaPickerController's view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my application I don't use the upper bar that displays Wi-Fi/Date/Time because it's a game. However I need to be able to let my user to pick his music, so I'm using a MPMediaPickerController. The problem is, that when I present my controller, the controller ends up leaving a 10 pixels ( aprox ) bar at the top of the screen, just in the place the Wi-Fi/Date/Time bar, should be present.

Is there a way I could make my MPMediaPickerController bigger ? or to be presented upper in the screen ?

```
// Configures and displays the media item picker.
- (void) showMediaPicker: (id) sender 
{ 
 MPMediaPickerController *picker =
 [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];

 [[picker view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

 picker.delegate      = self;
 picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
 picker.prompt      = NSLocalizedString (@"AddSongsPrompt", @"Prompt to user to choose some songs to play");

 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated: YES];
 [picker release];
}
```

There I tried to set the size to 320x480 but no luck, the picker is still presented and leaves a space in the upper part of the screen, could anyone help me ?

Btw, here's how it looks:

[alt text http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/1986/img0001yb.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/1986/img0001yb.png)

I have asked a bit, and people told me this could indeed be a bug, what do you guys think ?

Comment: not really, ended up using Mike Abdullah's solution.

Comment: What's more interesting - it works fine on iOS 5, but on iOS 4.2.1 this bug still exists. In my case the bar is white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could go two ways. Yes I'd say it's a bit of a bug that the picker doesn't resize accordingly, but it could also be argued that Apple expects the picker to operate in a non-full screen environment.

Rather than try to force it to work as you'd like, I'd instead recommend turning the status bar back on while the picker is visible:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

(To confirm, you are turing the status bar off in a similar fashion with your app, not just somehow painting over it?)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I am turning the status bar off via .plist var

Comment: So in which case your only option it seems is to temporarily turn it back on. Also, make sure you file a bug requesting that the picker handle this case. http://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
[[picker view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps?

```
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
picker.view.clipsToBounds = NO;
```